# Add style class to select_country field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails 4.

I installed `gem 'country_select', '~> 1.3.1'` and have the drop down working a little wierd. I cannot find the documentation on adding a style class to the field.

I need the id as it is used in a JS and I am trying to use a Bootstrap class with the field. Any drop down class would be nice:

```
<%= f.label :ship_country, "Country:" %><br>
<%= f.country_select :ship_country, {class: "dropdown", :id => "payment_ship_country"} %>
```

This shows a default select class that is ugly, it also is adding "class" and "id" as select options so the syntax is clearly way off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`class` and `id` are `html` options and they should be passed as third argument to the `country_select` method. The second argument is for list of options to be displayed in the drop-down which is why you see `id` and `class` as selectable options in your drop down instead of getting applied as html options.

You can do something like below:

```
<%= f.country_select :ship_country, {}, {class: "dropdown", :id => "payment_ship_country"} %>
```

For your reference, checkout below example from the `country_select` documentation:

```
Supplying additional html options:

country_select("user", "country", { priority_countries: ["GB", "FR"] }, { selected: "GB", class: 'form-control' })
```

This should work from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/country_select):

```
<%= f.country_select :ship_country, priority_countries = ["United States"], options = {}, html_options = {:class => "input-lg", :id => "payment_country"} %>
```

Comment: Very nice, this removed the unwanted options. The class does not go through. The browser loads the id fine though... I will test a few things. +1, The bootstrap dropdown.js is being loaded. hmmm

Comment: I read something saying it requires, data-toggle="dropdown" but I can't figure out how to add it.

Comment: Add it as part of html options with `class` and `id`

Comment: This is what I did, :data => {:toggle=>"dropdown"} but the nothing loads except for the id :(

Comment: Awesome, the f.country_select :ship_country, priority_countries = ["United States"], options = {}, html_options = {:class => "input-lg", :id => "payment_country"} worked perfectly!